# What is a correct design pattern for an API mailing/notification system?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, design-patterns, email

I am developing a **Rest API** using **node js**, **mongo** and **express** as technologies. My models include users, venues, etc. In addition each user has states. Examples of states could be when a user signup the first state is 'new_user', after one week the state must be 'first_week_user' and so on.

The purpose of these states is to notify the user according to his or her state. For example if a user like a picture and the user is in the first week (he has the 'first_week' state) so an email must be sent to him. I am in the design stage right now, so I want to know if somebody had to face the same issue before.

The design that I have in mind is to put a *notification_profile* inside the user object and using a cron job to check the state and the actions of the day and according to that send the emails/push notifications.

What do you think? Are there a better option? e.g. I can have an email API and queue the emails hitting this API. Do you know where I can find information about design patterns facing this problem?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail, this sounds like you need the [Observer](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/observer-design-pattern) pattern.

Essentially, your `Email` component would subscribe to each `Person` object's `like(photo photo)` event, and either execute an email-send job immediately, or schedule the job to run later, as part of a batch.

Answer (score 0):

One way to specify the state transitions would be as a hierarchical state machine.  See http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/hierarchicalstatemachine.htm#.VNJIflXF--o and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine

I don't have a good node.js example but [here's a C# implementation](https://github.com/IanMercer/AboditStateMachine/tree/master/AboditStateMachine/Abodit/StateMachine) that also includes the concept of timed events. Essentially the state machine keeps track of a `NextTimedEventAt` so you can efficiently pull it back out of a database at the right time to fire a time-based event.

Actions happen on state transitions: as you enter a state or leave a state.